# Ogone payment gateway integration?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

I am trying to create an application with ogone payment gateway integration. can you please tell me where can I start and is there any api or something available?

Rohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with C# and also have problems with integration of this payment provider.
In my search I have found one usefull link: https://cheddargetter.com/developers#add-customer
Wish this helps you. If I found something more concrete, will inform you.

Most of the posible manipulations with the Ogone payment provider can be found in direct link API: http://www.productivecomputing.com/docs/docs_library/FM_CreditCard/Ogone_DirectLink_EN.pdf